# How to do the pagination in SQL Server 2005 when multiple table used by joining

Tags: sql-server-2005, pagination

I know people use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to do the pagination but my below two query is bit complex. So I need suggestion like how to use pagination there ?

I used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IsNull(A.OEReference, B.OEReference) ASC) as Line` in one but not sure am I right or wrong.

```
 IF IsNull(@GroupID,'') = ''      
     SELECT  
         IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped') AS PartGroupName,      
         CASE IsNull(PartGroupName, '')      
            WHEN '' THEN ''       
            ELSE IsNull(IsNull(K.GroupID, IsNull(C.PartGroupID,'')),'')      
         END AS PartGroupID,      
         IsNull(A.OEReference, B.OEReference) AS OEReference,   
         IsNull(SaleDone,0) AS [SALE/OUR],        
         IsNull(WarrantyDone, 0) AS [WARRANTY/WARRANTYOUR]      
     FROM  
         @Sale A 
     FULL OUTER JOIN 
         @Warranty B ON A.OEReference = B.OEReference      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         BBAPart K ON IsNull(A.OEReference, B.OEReference) = K.Stock_code      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         BBAPartGroup C ON K.GroupID = C.PartGroupID AND C.IsDeleted = 0  
     ORDER BY 
         IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped')   
 ELSE      
     SELECT  
         IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped') AS PartGroupName,      
         CASE IsNull(PartGroupName, '')      
              WHEN '' THEN ''       
              ELSE IsNull(IsNull(K.GroupID, IsNull(C.PartGroupID,'')),'')      
         END AS PartGroupID,      
         IsNull(A.OEReference, B.OEReference) AS OEReference,   
         IsNull(SaleDone,0) AS [SALE/OUR],        
         IsNull(WarrantyDone, 0) AS [WARRANTY/WARRANTYOUR]
     FROM  
         @Sale A 
     FULL OUTER JOIN 
         @Warranty B ON A.OEReference = B.OEReference      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         BBAPart K ON IsNull(A.OEReference,B.OEReference) = K.Stock_code      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         BBAPartGroup C ON K.GroupID=C.PartGroupID AND C.IsDeleted = 0      
     WHERE  
         PartGroupID IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.stringtotable(@GroupID, ',') )      
     ORDER BY 
         IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped')   
END
```

### this way i have solved it

```
 IF IsNull(@GroupID,'') = ''  
 BEGIN    
   SELECT  COUNT(*) 
   FROM  @Sale A FULL OUTER JOIN @Warranty B ON A.OEReference = B.OEReference      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPart K ON IsNull(A.OEReference,B.OEReference) = K.Stock_code      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPartGroup C ON K.GroupID=C.PartGroupID AND C.IsDeleted = 0  


 SELECT *
  FROM (
  SELECT  IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped') AS PartGroupName,      
     CASE IsNull(PartGroupName, '')      
      WHEN '' THEN ''       
      ELSE IsNull(IsNull(K.GroupID, IsNull(C.PartGroupID,'')),'')      
     END AS PartGroupID,      
     IsNull(A.OEReference, B.OEReference) AS OEReference,   
     IsNull(SaleDone,0) AS [SALE/OUR],        
     IsNull(WarrantyDone, 0) AS [WARRANTY/WARRANTYOUR]
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped')  ) AS rn       
  FROM  @Sale A FULL OUTER JOIN @Warranty B ON A.OEReference = B.OEReference      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPart K ON IsNull(A.OEReference,B.OEReference) = K.Stock_code      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPartGroup C ON K.GroupID=C.PartGroupID AND C.IsDeleted = 0  
  --WHERE rn>= @StartIndex AND rn <= @EndIndex    
  --ORDER BY IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped')
  ) List_of_records
  WHERE [rn] BETWEEN ((@StartIndex-1) * @EndIndex ) + 1 AND (@StartIndex * @EndIndex)
  ORDER BY IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped')  
 END 
 ELSE      
 BEGIN
   SELECT  COUNT(*)     
   FROM  @Sale A FULL OUTER JOIN @Warranty B ON A.OEReference = B.OEReference      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPart K ON IsNull(A.OEReference,B.OEReference) = K.Stock_code      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPartGroup C ON K.GroupID=C.PartGroupID AND C.IsDeleted = 0      
  WHERE  PartGroupID IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.stringtotable(@GroupID, ',') )  


 SELECT *
  FROM (
  SELECT  IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped') AS PartGroupName,      
     CASE IsNull(PartGroupName, '')      
      WHEN '' THEN ''       
      ELSE IsNull(IsNull(K.GroupID, IsNull(C.PartGroupID,'')),'')      
     END AS PartGroupID,      
     IsNull(A.OEReference, B.OEReference) AS OEReference,   
     IsNull(SaleDone,0) AS [SALE/OUR],        
     IsNull(WarrantyDone, 0) AS [WARRANTY/WARRANTYOUR]
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped')  ) AS rn    
  FROM  @Sale A FULL OUTER JOIN @Warranty B ON A.OEReference = B.OEReference      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPart K ON IsNull(A.OEReference,B.OEReference) = K.Stock_code      
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BBAPartGroup C ON K.GroupID=C.PartGroupID AND C.IsDeleted = 0      
  WHERE  PartGroupID IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.stringtotable(@GroupID, ',') )  
  --AND rn>= @StartIndex AND rn <= @EndIndex    
  --ORDER BY IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped') 
  )  List_of_records
  WHERE [rn] BETWEEN ((@StartIndex-1) * @EndIndex ) + 1 AND (@StartIndex * @EndIndex)
  ORDER BY IsNull(PartGroupName, 'UnMapped')
  END
```